# Laravel Filament, Create customizable Dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am using laravel Filament 3, currently this is my code for the admin panel,
but I am trying to create a dashboard where user able to add and remove the widget in the dashboard

```php
->viteTheme('resources/css/filament/admin/theme.css')
->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Resources')
->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Pages')
->pages([Pages\Dashboard::class])
->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Widgets')
->widgets([
  Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
  // Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class
])
```

Comment: Asking for a "suggestion" on how to do something is somewhat subjective. It's better to ask a completely objective question to generate good answers.